# Signalr ConnectedUsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

i am new with asp.net mvc and signalr. I send message to all clients in my message app but i want private messaging and in this article under the title "private chat" codes are like belove:

```
public void SendPrivateMessage(string toUserId, string message)
{

    string fromUserId = Context.ConnectionId;
    var toUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == toUserId) ;
    var fromUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == fromUserId);

    if (toUser != null && fromUser!=null)
    {
       // send to
       Clients.Client(toUserId).sendPrivateMessage(fromUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);

       // send to caller user
       Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(toUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);
    }
}
```

question.1: Does fromUserId have to be a number or id not a name?
question.2: Where did Connectedusers defined?because i am getting error about it.
And here is my code that sends messages to all clients:

```
public void Send(string alici,string name,string message)
{
    Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    //alici:name of receiver, name:name of sender
}
```

Can i use alici to send message to a specific user and how?
thanks

Comment: Are you starting the hub when the page loads.

Comment: Yes, i guess, because i can send to all clients @Murtaza Munshi

Comment: Ok so are you maintaining a table or something like that for your users

Comment: Yes, `ConnectedUsers` is a list of `UserDetail` that we don't see here, but if you grab the source code from the [article that he is following](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room), you will see there.

Comment: @mervedemir Is this helpful in any way? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Answer for Question 1:

`toUserId` must me `ID` that will be almost similar to `GUID` (Uniqueidentifier), this will help you identify each user separately even if there will be two Users with same name.

Question 2 is answered by radu-matei and thats correct by far my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

`ConnectedUsers` is a list of `UserDetail`, which holds all the connected users. Now, you can either add them in the list when they connect to the hub (so you override the `OnConnected` method, either you create a server function, in this case `Connect`, which takes a `string userName` as parameter.(the `userName` that the user sets when first entering the page)).

Now, the `userId` is the `SignalR ConnectionId` that every client recieves when connecting the hub.

```
    public void Connect(string userName)
{

   var id = Context.ConnectionId;

   if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
   {

       ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });

       // send to caller
       Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);

       // send to all except caller client
       Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName);

   }

}
```

This is the `Connect` method on the server side. Notice how a client is only added if there isn't anybody else with that `ConnectionId.`

Sure you can send a message to someone based on their name, but at some point you will have to deal with 2 people having the same name; it is always better to have non-repeating IDs as identifiers than names.

Hope this helps! Best of luck!